# Getting an error that ggplot2_3.2.0 can't draw more than one boxplot per group

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have `xy` data that I'd like to plot using `R`'s `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(group = unlist(lapply(LETTERS[1:5],function(l) rep(l,5))),
                 x = rep(1:5,5),
                 y = rnorm(25,2,1),
                 y.se = runif(25,0,0.1)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(y.min = y-3*y.se,
                y.low = y-y.se,
                y.high = y+y.se,
                y.max = y+3*y.se)
```

As you can see, while `df$x` is a point (`integer`), `df$y` has an associated error, which I would like to include using a box plot.

So my purpose is to plot each row in `df` by its `x` coordinate, using `y.min`, `y.low`, `y`, `y.high`, and `y.max` to construct a `boxplot`, and `color` and `fill` it by `group`. That means, that I'd like to have each row in `df`, plotted as a `box` along a separate `x-axis` location and `faceted` by `df$group`, such that `df$group` `A`'s five replicates appear first, then to their right `df$group` `B`'s replicates, and so on.

This code used to work for my purpose until I just installed the latest `ggplot2` package (`ggplot2_3.2.0`):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,ymin=y.min,lower=y.low,middle=y,upper=y.high,ymax=y.max,col=group,fill=group))+
geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+
facet_grid(~group,scales="free_x")+scale_x_continuous(breaks = integerBreaks())
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm getting the same new error, and my boxplot does not have groups or facets.

Comment: Looks like they patched something and now the group aesthetic is required. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3316

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news/news.html (see 3.2.0)

Answer (score 4):

You need a separate boxplot for each combination of `x` and `group`, so you can set the group aesthetic to `interaction(x, group)`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,ymin=y.min,lower=y.low,middle=y,upper=y.high,
              ymax=y.max,col=group,fill=group))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(x, group)), 
                 position=position_dodge(width=0),
                 alpha=0.5,stat="identity")
```

Comment: Thanks `@Marius`, but this makes the boxes of each group appear on the same `x-axis` location. My intention was that each box has a separate `x-axis` location. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: The boxes are appearing at the same x-axis location because you have `width = 0` in `position_dodge`, I assumed that was intentional. With `width = 0.9` they will be spread out.

Comment: Thanks!. How about changing the order on the x-axis such that it is first ordered by `df$group` and then by `df$x`?

Answer (score 4):

> This code used to work for my purpose until I just installed the
>   latest ggplot2 package (ggplot2_3.2.0)

You are right: I just experienced a similar error with a code I recently wrote using ggplot2 boxplots, and just find out this new error related to ggplot2 latest update.
As Marius already pointed out, specifying the `group` in the `aes()` did solve the problem for me also.
However I don't understand the rest of his answer, as it is not providing the faceting...

Here is a working solution with `facet_grid()`, you were close:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,ymin=y.min,lower=y.low,middle=y,upper=y.high,ymax=y.max,col=group,fill=group, group=x))+
geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+
facet_grid(~group,scales="free_x")
```

[image]