# Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using the following code to create boxplot in ggplot2 version 3.3.0:

```
set.seed(240193)
df1 <- data.frame(person=rep(c("a","b"),each = 10),
                  score=c(rnorm(10,8,1),rnorm(10,6,1.5)))

df1 <- df1 %>% 
         group_by(person) %>% 
         mutate(d_ymin = min(score),
                d_ymax = max(score),
                d_lower = quantile(score, 0.25),
                d_middle = median(score),
                d_upper = quantile(score, 0.75))

p1 <- ggplot(df1) + 
     geom_boxplot(aes(x = person,
                      ymin = d_ymin,
                      lower = d_lower,
                      middle = d_middle,
                      upper = d_upper,
                      ymax = d_ymax,
                      fill = person), stat = "identity")

p2 <- ggplot(df1)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=person,y=score), width=0.1)
```

`p1` cannot be created becuase of the error "Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?"
"Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred". `p2` is fine.

I noted the earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192727/getting-an-error-that-ggplot2-3-2-0-cant-draw-more-than-one-boxplot-per-group#) describing this issue as associated with update of ggplot2 version 3.2.0. As I could understand, the critical point is a group aesthetic that has a unique value for each boxplot that should be drawn. So the trick is `aes(group = interaction(x, group)` as answered by Marius. However, the example in that post has two variables so that the `interaction` function can be used. Here in my example, I have only one grouping variable, the `person`. This means the data structure naturally gives each box plot a unique value in the `fill` aesthetic. Changing `fill` to `group` did not help either.

So what is wrong with the code now that each box plot has already been give a unique group aesthetic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are to provide the statistics for the boxplot, it should be one value per group, so instead of doing `mutate()`, try `summarize()` :

```
set.seed(240193)
df1 <- data.frame(person=rep(c("a","b"),each = 10),
                  score=c(rnorm(10,8,1),rnorm(10,6,1.5)))

df1 <- df1 %>% 
         group_by(person) %>% 
         summarize(d_ymin = min(score),
                d_ymax = max(score),
                d_lower = quantile(score, 0.25),
                d_middle = median(score),
                d_upper = quantile(score, 0.75))

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  person d_ymin d_ymax d_lower d_middle d_upper
  <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 a        5.47   8.93    7.47     8.11    8.23
2 b        2.43   9.89    4.97     6.32    6.86
```

Then plot:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df1) + 
     geom_boxplot(aes(x = person,
                      ymin = d_ymin,
                      lower = d_lower,
                      middle = d_middle,
                      upper = d_upper,
                      ymax = d_ymax,
                      fill = person), stat = "identity")
```

[image]