# Error message suggesting grouping of the x-axis variable when creating boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to replicate this boxplot example found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-boxplot-using-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-r).

I get this error message:

```
Error in `geom_boxplot()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `draw_group()`:
! Can only draw one boxplot per group
ℹ Did you forget `aes(group = ...)`?
```

I think the error message is misleading because the example doesn't use `aes(group = ...)`. Also, my data frame is similar, so what is the matter? Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=variable))+geom_boxplot(aes(lower=mean-sd,upper=mean+sd,middle=mean,ymin=mean-3*sd,ymax=mean+3*sd),stat="identity")
```

My data:

```
structure(list(mean = c(6, 6, 6, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 6, 6, 6, 4.3, 
4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3), sd = c(0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 
0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 
0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 
0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 0.884872872225158, 
0.884872872225158), variable = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", 
"x3", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"), 
    value = c(5, 4, 9, 8, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You have multiple boxplots per group, see here for solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192727/getting-an-error-that-ggplot2-3-2-0-cant-draw-more-than-one-boxplot-per-group

Comment: Your data doens't match that example. They only have one row per "Category" on the x-axis. You are putting "variable" on the axis but you have multiple rows per "variable". You have x1 with a mean of 6, 5.7, and 4.3. What exactly should be drawn on the plot? It's not clear what the desired result should look like.

Comment: @MrFlick I want a boxplot where x1, x2 and x3 have their own boxes that show their mean and sd. We can think about them as three time points of measurement

Comment: So how many boxes total will there be for x1? Just one? Or one for each mean? If it's just one, where should the mean line be; the mean of the Mean column? And then what do you want to do with SD because the SD of the Mean column probably won't be the same as the SD you have in the sd column.

Comment: Just one box for x1. The three variables are three time points of measurement of the same group of people. The mean line should be like in this example. Actually I have no idea what to with SD in this case 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-boxplot-using-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-r